# How to send sms to phone number with twilio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twilio

I have created the ajax call for twilio sms verificaton with jquery. I'm passing all parameters correctly and getting positive response only, but that messages not delivered to that number. 
Here is my ajax code,

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            // Your Twilio credentials
            var SID = "SID_KEY";
            var Key = "AUTH_TOKEN";

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'+SID+'/Messages',
                data: {
                    "To" : "+xxxxxxxxxx",
                    "From" : "+yyyyyyyyy",
                    "Body" : "Hello World"
                },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(SID + ':' + Key));
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(1);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Response,

```
account_sid: "SID_KEY"
        api_version: "2010-04-01"
        body: "Sent from your Twilio trial account - Hello World"
        date_created: "Sun, 27 Nov 2016 18:08:55 +0000"
        date_sent: null
        date_updated: "Sun, 27 Nov 2016 18:08:55 +0000"
        direction: "outbound-api"
        error_code: null
        error_message: null
        from: "+yyyyyyyyy"
        messaging_service_sid: null
        num_media: "0"
        num_segments: "1"
        price: null
        price_unit: "USD"
        sid: "SM2dfdfdsdadgdgadf33542352"
        status: "queued"
        to: "+xxxxxxxx"
        uri: "/2010-04-01/Accounts/SID_KEY/Messages/SM2dfdfdsdadgdgadf33542352.json"
```

Comment: So what is api response? Not much detail provided here

Comment: you better hide the SID and Key as a confidential info

Comment: The data is still accessible throug the changelog. You better delete the question to avoid abuse of it.

Comment: I have updated the response in my question @charlietfl...

Comment: This is trial account only. Anyway i deleted the SID key

Comment: Watch this `status: "queued"`. Your code is working perfectly fine.

Comment: how long it will take to recieve sms? @AniketSahrawat

Comment: Really can't say anything about it. IMO you should try contacting to twilio's customer support or plan for a upgrade maybe.

Comment: Another Question regarding your code security, how you are going to protect the `SID` and `Key` when you are going live as this is used inside the js file. Recommended approach is calling twillio from your server.